# How to avoid repetitive sql connection code in nodejs and have a .env file instead

Tags: mysql, node.js, refactoring

I have the following porject in which i need to connect to my MySql database quite often and i have folloing code as of now repeating in quite a few places for me:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'indegene@123',
    database : 'mytasks'
  });
```

( The entire index.js file can be seen **[HERE](https://github.com/gautamz07/Chios/blob/master/routes/index.js#L15)** ).

My question is how do i avoid the repetitive code of logging into a database and instead have it in something like a .env file or something ?

Comment: You could make it as a separate module and import your connection when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a *function* that encapsulates the repeating code, and call the function every time you need to evaluate it. Namely:

```
function createDbConnection() { 
    return mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : 'indegene@123',
        database : 'mytasks'
    });
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  var connection = createDbConnection();

  connection.connect( );

  // ... do the needed stuff using connection

});

// ... and likewise for each endpoint definition ...
```

Furthermore, if you want to use the connection creation in different source files, you can just include the function in a separate file and using it by requiring that file.